# Compare List Page Customization

Tags: magento-1.7, theme, product-list

I need to show custom attributes for the products selected to compare in the same fashion I can show them on the Product View page.  The code that I have been using in the Compare List page to return the attributes is

```
<?php $attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'blade_length'); ?>
<span class="left-label">
<?php echo $attribute->getFrontend()->getLabel(); ?></span>
<span class="right-info">
<?php echo$this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_item, $_item->getBladeLength(),'blade_length') ?></span>
```

Unfortunately, this does not provide me with the necessary access to all of the attributes for the selected products.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: have you tried loading the product first? If that's too expensive I remember doing something like this Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($productId, 'attribute_code', $storeId);

Comment: Thanks Thomas for the suggestion.  I am not sure how I would go about loading the product on the Compare List template.  I tried to do it a few different ways but was unsuccessful.  I am going to try you other suggestion and post my results.

Comment: I could be misunderstanding the situation but loading a product usually works by ---- $product->load() and then it pulls all of it's attributes. Only down side is that it can slow the thing down

Answer (score 2):

You can just mark the attribute `blade_length` as `Comparable on Front-end` from the backend (`Catalog->Attributes->Manage attribtues`) and reindex.
This should make it appear in the list of attributes in the compare page.